# Read Basic InputStream - Java

Tags: java

I'm calling a SOAP webservice that returns a document as DataHandler.

I'm trying to read it but I get

> org.apache.axiom.om.OMException: Failed to fetch the MIME part content
>   Caused by: java.io.IOException: Attempted read on closed stream.

at `InputStream documentData = dataHandler.getInputStream();`

```
public byte[] retrieveDocument(String documentID) { 
    try {

        RetrieveDocumentRequest request = new RetrieveDocumentRequest();
        request.setDocumentId(documentID);
        request.setRequestHeader(getRequestHeader());

        RetrieveDocumentResponse response = stub.retrieveDocument(request);
        DataHandler dataHandler = response.getDataHandler();
        InputStream documentData = dataHandler.getInputStream();

        return IOUtils.toByteArray(documentData);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return null;
}
```

How do I get the document if the InputStream is closed?

Comment: Any ideas? Thanks

Comment: Related or even a duplicate: [Java Axis2 using MTOM: “Attempted read on closed stream”](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49297229/java-axis2-using-mtom-attempted-read-on-closed-stream)

Comment: my guess: you already closed the stream due to some call beforehand (releaseConnection?) or you already consumed and close it, without really realizing... (try-with-resources?)

Comment: Debug the response and its fields